# manage users by an admin in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how can I manage and edit other users profiles as an admin since I have one model and controller (users) ?

I tried to add a new action called updateusers

```
def updateusers
    @other_user=User.find(params[:id])
    if @other_user.update_attributes(otherusers_params) 
            redirect_to '/' 
    else
            redirect_to '/manage'
   end
end
```

the problem here :it is updating my admin user with the other_user's data

**stack trace**
Started GET "/manage" for ::1 at 2016-03-19 21:06:08 +0300 Processing by UsersController#manage as HTML User Load (1.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" Rendered users/manage.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms) User Load (0.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", 1]] Completed 200 OK in 53ms (Views: 51.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

'Started GET "/users/10" for ::1 at 2016-03-19 21:06:10 +0300 Processing by UsersController#show as HTML Parameters: {"id"=>"10"} User Load (0.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", 10]] Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms) User Load (0.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", 1]] Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 36.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/editusers/10" for ::1 at 2016-03-19 21:06:11 +0300 Processing by UsersController#editusers as HTML Parameters: {"id"=>"10"} User Load (0.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", 10]] Rendered users/editusers.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms) User Load (1.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", 1]] Completed 200 OK in 41ms (Views: 39.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

Started PATCH "/users/10" for ::1 at 2016-03-19 21:06:15 +0300 Processing by UsersController#update as HTML Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6M1TGLQUEhiezCCg9/rT5IofdroMiQ0sm+bYcihgGDxTjDdFGU2Riou2p‌​cRk5ncjCtFDGwfBj17Uq7gc0u329w==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"g", "last_name"=>"g", "email"=>"g@g.g", "role"=>"editor", "image"=>"pic.png", "admins"=>""}, "other"=>"update", "id"=>"10"} User Load (0.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", 1]] 
Unpermitted parameters: role, admins

(0.0ms) begin transaction SQL (1.0ms) UPDATE "users" SET "first_name" = ?, "last_name" = ?, "email" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ? [["first_name", "g"], ["last_name", "g"], ["email", "g@g.g"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-19 18:06:15.488284"], ["id", 1]] (47.0ms) commit transaction Redirected to localhost:8080/profile Completed 302 Found in 54ms (ActiveRecord: 48.0ms)

Comment: the ID you are passing `params[:id]` is for the other user?

Comment: I'd suggest using the activeadmin gem instead of writing your own admin system.

http://activeadmin.info/

Comment: Yes
in the show and edit views give me the data of the other user

Comment: I'll try the active admin, but with mine I'm in the last step 
is there a way to handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 10 days ,, Yes i did it - the solution is in **the name of submit** , I named the two submits with diffrent names `<%= f.submit "update", name:"other" %>`
then i used the update action like this

```
def update 
    if params[:current]
       @user = current_user
       if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
          redirect_to '/profile'
       else 
          redirect_to '/edit'
       end 

     elsif params[:other]
         @other_user=User.find(params[:id])
         if @other_user.update_attributes(otherusers_params)
            redirect_to '/'
          else 
             redirect_to '/manage'
          end 
     end 

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's updating the wrong user, it means that `params[:id]` is the id of the user being updated. Are you passing the id of the user you want to update in the params? Try calling `puts params.inspect` at the top of the controller action to see what data is being passed. You need to look up @other_user with their id and you need to make sure that @other_user's id is being passed with the other form data.

Comment: I think it is not reading the new update action (updateusers), it still read the original update action ??!! i have two update actions one for the current_user and one for the admin to update the other users

Comment: patch '/users/update' => 'users#update' -- the original 
  ----
  patch 'users/:id/updateusers' => 'users#updateusers'
  put   'users/:id/updateusers' => 'users#updateusers'

Comment: what does the stack trace show (in terminal) when you submit the form?

Comment: sorry for the long flow 
this is all the steps form show upto the end of the process

Comment: I would maybe update the question w/ this stack trace...lots of useful stuff in there. You can also put it all in one place and format it better.

Comment: i can not put them in the same comment "TOO LONG"

Comment: @yemeniDream in the question.

Comment: the question Edited :)